# Netbeans android plugin is not generating project.properties

Tags: android, plugins, netbeans

I am using NBAndroid plugin with Netbeans 7.0.1. I don't know nbandroid version. I installed latest couple of days back.  When I create a project, it seems to generate all the files except project.properties.
When I build, the build is failing because of missing file.
I renamed default.properties to project.properties. Then it is working fine.
Later I found that a reference library that I added is not being used when compiling the code resulting in lot of errors.
I suspect my project is not setup correctly.

I am using the plugin on MacOSX.

Thanks for help.
Video Guy

Answer (score 0):

The Netbeans android plugin uses Android tool to generate the build.xml file. The build.xml imports xml files from <androidsdk>/tools/ant folder.

The tools folder got an update when I updated the sdk after Icecream sandwitch release. Now it uses completely different set of xml files etc. The Netbeans Android plugin is not uptodate yet.

Once I manually updated the project files using <androidsdk>/tools/android tool, the project got into buildable state.